# Webpage deployment

Tags: web, web-development-server, react-fullstack

Hello I have a webpage that stores videos, payments and authentications. I have a frontend in react and backend in node. What do I need to deploy my page, and where can I find a good but cheap solution? Will also be adding more videos later on through a self made admin panel

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to learn you can use `Heroku`
- If you are running on production , you can deploy to (Digital Ocean or OVH) VPS.

Then : You should use `PM2` to deploy